# Format Date to Year

Tags: angularjs

I've got a date coming in from an API that returns the date like this: 2012-10-12 00:00:00

I'm printing it to my page like this:

```
<span class="year" ng-bind-html="hit._highlightResult.original_release_date.value"></span>
```

with `original_release_date.value` being that date (2012-10-12 00:00:00). Does anyone know a quick and easy way to just return the year?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use something like `var myDate = new Date(dateFromServer)`? I am not sure if it'll work on Safari.
Then you can get the year just by `myDate.getFullYear();`

Answer (score 3):

you can use the [date api](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) in angularjs

```
<span class="year"> {{ hit._highlightResult.original_release_date.value |  date:"yyyy" }} </span>
```

`hit._highlightResult.original_release_date.value` should be a (according to doc)

> Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number) or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats (e.g. yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ and its shorter versions like yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ). If no timezone is specified in the string input, the time is considered to be in the local timezone.

so create `javascript date` object and format it to show only the year,

**step 1 - create a filter to get a date object from a string (2012-10-12 00:00:00)**

```
app.filter('dateToISO', function() {
    return  function(input) {
       var dateTime = input.split(" ");
       var date = dateTime[0];
       var datePartials = date.split("-");
       var time = dateTime[1];
       var timePartials = time.split(":");
       var formattedDate = new Date();
       formattedDate.setFullYear(datePartials[0]);
       formattedDate.setMonth(datePartials[1]-1);
       formattedDate.setDate(datePartials[2]);
       formattedDate.setHours(timePartials[0]);
       formattedDate.setMinutes(timePartials[1]);
       return formattedDate;
    };
});
```

**step 2 - create a controller function to get the `date object`**

```
$scope.getDate = function() {
    return $filter('dateToISO')('2012-10-12 00:00:00');
};
```

**step 3 - call that function and get the date object to format in the HTML**

```
<span class="year"> {{ getDate() |  date:"yyyy" }} </span>
```

here is the working [Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cyJA9Op02N9nqdNW00nf?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for this! But it doesn't seem to be working. My date is still being displayed as "2012-10-12 00:00:00". It's worth mentioning that it's stored in the database as a string. Would that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Or perhaps, this date: 2012-10-12 00:00:00, needs to be in this format: 1288323623006

Comment: Weird. Even {{ 2012-10-12 00:00:00 | date: "yyyy" }} returns 2012-10-12 00:00:00.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit off and cheating but I think '2012-10-12 00:00:00'.split('-')[0] will do the trick